# how to merge item in the cart into one product session Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a tough question but I don't have much reputation to add bounty for answering.
I need to merge on item that show up in my cart into one product just as 1 variation product in woocmmerce.
I think it could be a solution, like item in the cart is an array, so i want to make new array of all product array and possibly give it a name!
Please Help :)

Comment: What items are you merging? Why do they need to be merged? What is your end goal? You need to provide a lot more detail before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I want to show up a 'mix' button & text input above 'checkout' button after 3 items are exist in cart (cart widget-right side).
if user hit mix, items in cart will MERGE into 1 item (instead of 9 items - 9 items max) with product name from user input.
So ultimately users can create their own mix, they can create mix 1, mix 2,....carrying a lot of product for every mix.

my website of working on: http://gotheelz.com
The model website: e-zigi.de/mixxxer.php